# initialize struct contain references to structs

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, initialization

Is it possible to have a struct containing references to structs. And how are these initialized? See short example below.

Thanks

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
}typeInner1;


typedef struct {
  int b;
}typeInner2;


typedef struct {
  typeInner1 &one;
  typeInner2 &two;
}typeOuter;

void fun2(typeOuter *p){
  p->one.a =2;
  p->two.b =3;
}


void fun(typeInner1 &arg1,typeInner2 &arg2){
  typeOuter *ptr = new typeOuter;//<-- how to write initializer
  fun2(ptr);
}


int main(){
  typeInner1 arg1;
  typeInner2 arg2;
  fun(arg1,arg2);

  //now arg1.a should be 2 and arg2.a=3
}
```

Ok thanks for all the input. I also had to modify the typedef of the typeOuter to make it work. Full working code below for other people finding this post.

```
#include <cstdio>
typedef struct {
  int a;
}typeInner1;


typedef struct {
  int b;
}typeInner2;


typedef struct typeOuter_t {
  typeInner1 &one;
  typeInner2 &two;
  typeOuter_t(typeInner1 &a1, typeInner2 &a2) : one(a1), two(a2) {}
}typeOuter;

void fun2(typeOuter *p){
  p->one.a =2;
  p->two.b =3;
}


void fun(typeInner1 &arg1,typeInner2 &arg2){
  typeOuter *ptr = new typeOuter(arg1,arg2);
  fun2(ptr);
}


int main(){
  typeInner1 arg1;
  typeInner2 arg2;
  fun(arg1,arg2);

  //now arg1.a shoule be 1 and arg2.a=3
  fprintf(stderr,"arg1=%d arg2=%d\n",arg1.a,arg2.b);
}
```

Comment: BTW, `typedef struct {...} foo;` is not "idiomatic" in C++, simply writing `struct foo {...};` is more usual (and does let you use `foo` as a type name directly).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give `typeOuter` an appropriate constructor:

```
struct typeOuter
{
  typeInner1 &one;
  typeInner2 &two;
  typeOuter(typeInner1 &a1, typeInner2 &a2) : one(a1), two(a2) {}
};



void fun(typeInner1 &arg1, typeInner2 &arg2) {
  typeOuter *ptr = new typeOuter(arg1, arg2);
  fun2(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Before C++11, you will need a constructor for your struct `typeOuter`, and initialize the member references in the initializer list:

```
typeOuter(typeInner1& i1, typeInner2& i2) : one(i1), two(i2) {}
```

With C++11 you also have the option of using an initializer list directly (without defining a constructor yourself):

```
typeOuter *ptr = new typeOuter { arg1, arg2 };
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you can create a constructor for your `struct`. Structs are basically classes with `public` as default access modifier.

```
struct Example
{
    // struct fields..

    Example(); // initialize struct objects.
    ~Example(); // perform clean up if necessary.
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not with having references to `struct`s, but with initializing references in general. References cannot be default-initialized, no matter whether they are references to a `struct` or to a built-in type.

```
int& x; // ERROR! Non-initialized reference to int
C& y; // ERROR! Non-initialized reference to a struct C
int z;
C w;
int& a = z; // OK: Initialized reference to int
C& b = w; // OK: Initialized reference to struct C
```

When your references are member variables of a `struct`, on the other hand (no matter what type they refer to), they must be bound as soon as your `struct` is constructed (just as regular references). Default-constructing your `struct` and then binding the references is not an option, because it is done in two steps, and references would be uninitialized after the first step.

Therefore, you have to provide a *constructor* for your `struct` and initialize your references there:

```
struct typeOuter {
  typeOuter(typeInner1& o, typeInner2& t) : one(o), two(t) { }
  typeInner1 &one;
  typeInner2 &two;
};
```

Your `fun()` function would then look like this:

```
void fun(typeInner1 &arg1,typeInner2 &arg2){
    typeOuter *ptr = new typeOuter(arg1, arg2);
    fun2(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a constructor, but you can also use aggregate initialization along with a factory function. This works in all versions of C++:

```
struct A
{
   int& i;
};

A make_a(int& i)
{
   A a = {i};
   return a;
}

int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   A* a = new A(make_a(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm..

```
#include <cstdio>

struct typeInner1
{
    typeInner1(int a = 0) : m_a(a) {} // typeInner1 constructor
    int m_a;
};

struct typeInner2
{
    typeInner2(int b = 0) : m_b(b) {} // typeInner2 constructor
    int m_b;
};

struct typeOuter
{
    typeOuter(typeInner1& one, typeInner2& two) : m_one(one), m_two(two) {} // typeOuter constructor

    typeOuter& set(int a, int b) { m_one.m_a = a; m_two.m_b = b; return *this; }
    typeOuter& print() { printf("typeInner1 a is %i and typeInner2 b is %i\n", m_one.m_a, m_two.m_b); return *this; }

    typeInner1& m_one;
    typeInner2& m_two;
};

typeOuter fun(typeInner1& arg1, typeInner2& arg2)
{
    return typeOuter(arg1, arg2);
}

int main()
{
  typeInner1 arg1;
  typeInner2 arg2;

  fun(arg1, arg2).print().set(101, 202).print().set(202, 303).print();

  return 0;
}
```

Outputs

```
typeInner1 a is 0 and typeInner2 b is 0
typeInner1 a is 101 and typeInner2 b is 202
typeInner1 a is 202 and typeInner2 b is 303
```